# Skype status bar

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, xcode, skype

I developed an app but when you are calling with skype and skype is in background the red status bar shows up. This make a mess in my app, The contents scroll down for let the skype status bar fit. How can I fix this? Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Implement proper resizing in your view. You can do this in interface builder

Comment: Besides that this is the correct solution, I'd just like to add that you get a bigger status bar also when doing a normal phone call and using your app. In that case the status bar is green, IIRC.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't get where you mean. Do you mean under "View" "Mode" "Scale To Fill, Aspect Fit...."? What I have to use then? Thanks.

Comment: @Elio I meant the view resizing masks. ( you know, the arrows with the box ) -- note that if your content is so filled that you do not have enough space for all your controls when the status bar is bigger I would recommend taking a different approach on your UI

Comment: I tried as you told me but It's still not working :( I did this: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/991615/view.jpg

Comment: Euh the resizing mask you set there, it depends on the layout of your UIView whether that is going to work, can't tell you much more